# How to display android view class and widgets in xml

Tags: android, xml, layout, view

I am trying to display a class that extends View at the top of the screen and two texviews and a button below it in an xml layout, but either the view is only showed without the buttons below, or the view and buttons below are showed if I hard code the view height to 400dp, any help would be really appreciated,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/rl"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">


 <view class="....MyView"
    android:id="@+id/myView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" //"400dp"
    />

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/graphCntrls"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/myView"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvXCoord"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="x coordinate"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvYCoord"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="y coordinate"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/coordsCalcBttn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Calc" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe myview.wrap_content fills the entire screen and that's the problem? How do you set the view height for MyView?

Comment: I did not set the height for MyView, its constructor is defined like this         public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
       super(context, attr);} and it overrides onDraw(Canvas canvas)

Comment: Sorry for late response, I also tried changing layout_height to match_parent and fill_parent, still the widgets below are not shown

Comment: Have you tried making the parent outer layout a vertical linearlayout instead of using a relativelayout for this?

Comment: I just did and no change

Comment: I have seen on some code, where widths and heights are set to 0dp, and layout is correctly displayed, I don't know if this could help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default size is of CustomView is 0. Unless it has subviews (and is derived from a layout class which defines `onLayout`), in which case the default size is the sum of its children.

If you want to use `wrap_content` on a custom view that isn't just a collection of child views, you need to override on `onLayout()` and/or `onMeasure()`

Here is the work around:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <com.droid.pmk.stackoverflow1.MyView
        android:id="@+id/myView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ccc"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/graphCntrls"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/myView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvXCoord"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="x coordinate"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvYCoord"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="y coordinate"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/coordsCalcBttn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Calc"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to change the default behaviour of View in our custom view, then we need to override onMeasure. So measuring the CustomView is part of layout process which consists of two main steps : `measuring and layouting`.
The measure pass sets how big the view should be, the dimensions of it, and that the layout pass sets where to place the view, the position of it.

The layout part is only interesting for **views with children**, in other words views that inherits from `ViewGroup`.

**So if you put your `CustomView` below the `LinearLayout`, then it works fine as you expected**. But your View would be below the Layout and that is undesired as per your needs for layouting.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/graphCntrls"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvXCoord"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="x coordinate"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvYCoord"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="y coordinate"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/coordsCalcBttn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Calc"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <com.droid.pmk.stackoverflow1.MyView
        android:id="@+id/myView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_below="@id/graphCntrls"
        android:background="#ccc"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

This indicates that `wrap_content` will give your `MyView` the permission to take as much of the RelativeLayout as it needs. In your case the left out whole screen.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Pavitra for the insightful response, it works perfectly.

Comment: Glad to be of help @user1420482